# How to removing internal meshes from the stack of cubes?

Tags: modeling, faces, optimization, point-clouds

I have a created a model with a stack of cubes that forms one big single model. There are so many unnecessary faces and cubes present inside the model. I have to remove all the internal faces to render effectively.

The problem is I should not do it manually since there are millions of faces needs removed. And this is not my one and only model, I have to do it like this for many more models.Only if I can do it with the functions present in blender I can able to script it.

So if anyone of you faced a similar issue before please guide me. Or is there any plugin or tool to remove the internal meshes? I believe there has to be a way for this issue since those who use 3D printers are doing a similar kind of process.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Usually it is easier not to create internal faces than to remove them once they are created. It depends on that "stack of cubes" you have since if they are arrayed-like, it would be easier to array cubes without top and bottom faces. It might not be applicable, again, depending on the task you do.

Comment: Can you clarify as to whether they are arranged like [voxels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voxel) Related. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319655/how-to-do-face-removal-in-a-unit-cube-world-a-la-minecraft  Could build a kdtree from first face centre to rest , mark to remove if at same loc as next or keep otherwise.  Then do same with  set of next nearest  and so on until all are either kept or removed.